# Checking changes made before/after installing application?

Tags: linux, installation, filesystemwatcher

On Linux, I need to know which files were added/modified/moved/deleted after compiling and installing an application from source code, ie. the command-line, Linux equivalent to the venerale [InCtrl5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InCtrl5).

Is there a utility that does this, or a set of commands that I could run and would show me the  changes?

Thank you.

---

Edit: The following commands are sort of OK, but I don't need to know the line numbers on which changes occured or that "./.." were updated:

```
# ls -aR /tmp > b4.txt
# touch /tmp/test.txt
# ls -aR /tmp > after.txt
# diff -u b4.txt after.txt
```

Comment: Another case for superuser.com

Comment: But then, 1) developers perform this type of task, and 2) SO has a much bigger audience than SU :-/

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to know *which* files were touched, then you can use `find` for this:

```
touch /tmp/MARK
# install application here
find / -newercm /tmp/MARK
```

This will show you *all* files whose contents or metadata have changed since you touched `/tmp/MARK` (including newly added files).

Comment: Thanks but I need to know all the changes made by installing the application, not just to know if the contents of pre-existing files were modified.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use something like Mercurial (version control) to do this.

The main reason, is that it is not only effective but it is also clean, since it will only add a hidden directory to the top of the tree where you want to check these changes.

Let's say that you need to know what files changed in `/etc/`. So before installation (you need to have mercurial installed) you add the directory to mercurial:

```
cd /etc
hg init
hg add
hg ci -m "adding all files in /etc/ to track them down"
```

The above will effectively "add" all the files to track them. To verify nothing has changed:

```
hg st
```

Should return no files.

If you (or the installation) modifies a file, you should see something like this:

```
hg st
M foo.sh
```

The "M" before the file states the given file was modified.

For new files you would see a `?` before the file like:

```
? bar.sh
```

After you are done and no longer want Mercurial, simple remove the hidden directory:

```
cd /etc
rm -rf .hg
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for something using standard commands.